# Unable to pull most page insights metrics using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am attempting to pull page insights metrics using the Facebook Graph API Explorer, but only a handful seem to be accessible. After failing to pull these metrics using the "read_insights" permission, I checked every box from "User Data Permissions", "Friends Data Permissions", and "Extended permissions." I still can not access most metrics.

An example GET request:

//insights/page_fans

...returns an empty dataset even though I am an administrator of this page and have permission to access to this data. I currently only get data back from: page_story_adds_unique, page_friends_of_fans, page_admin_num_posts, page_admin_num_posts_by_week.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16894466/897489 - the default time span Facebook uses is not working because they appear to have missing data. You need to use `since` and `until` to get anything useful out.