# Facebook Graph API Explorer problem with page access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have problems receiving data from the Graph API Explorer.
I was following along this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2022/11/08/getting-started-with-page-insights-api/).
I already checked those posts on stackoverflow: [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43101957/how-to-get-results-from-facebook-insights-api) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781756/unable-to-retrieve-page-insights-using-graph-api-explorer)

So I wanted to extract the same metrics but for other months like in the tutorial and built the following request (I anonymzed the business page id here):

```
123456789/insights?access_token={page-access-token}&metric=page_engaged_users,page_impressions&since=2023-07-01&until=2023-08-02&period=day
```

But I receive the following error/response:

```
    {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#190) This method must be called with a Page Access Token",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 190,
    "fbtrace_id": "A2g9JAQDZugWAFDHTysAr9O"
  }
}
```

I added "read_insights", "pages_show_list" and "pages_read_engagement" to my permissions but it does not work :-/ Even when replacing {page-access-token} with the real token in the request bar it is not working.

I've also made a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Any ideas?

**Edit**
I added some screenshots how my tokens were set up:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Don't put the token into the request parameters yourself, GAE will do that for you. Just _select_ the correct token in the panel on the right - you currently have that field set to use the user token, so switch to page token.

Comment: Hi, I tried that and it always switched me back to the user token again.

Comment: What does that mean, "switches" you back? Does it _list_ any page tokens to begin with, when you open that dropdown? If not, you probably did not select the relevant pages, when you granted the necessary permission.

Comment: In the dropdown with the "user-token" I click on "request page-token" --> it then asks me if I want to reconnect "Connect you again with SM_Extrakt" --> I click reconnect and nothing changes.

Comment: I also tested it with a new app. I selected "company account (optional)" and then I selected my company.  Then I opened up the graph api explorer and selected the new app. Then I click on the drop down "request access token". I chose then "page access token" --> "continue as Andre" --> I select my company --> check the permissions and click save. It then shows me a "user token" . Wait a sec I'll add some screenshots in the question above

Comment: I don't know what you are even talking about there now, with selecting "company account" ...?

Comment: When creating an app in meta developers I can connect it to a business profile (as an optional step). This is what I meant with selecting the company account, sorry for misleading.

Comment: What does `/me/accounts`, requested with your user token, result in? Do you see the page in question listed there?

Comment: Nope the data field is empty :-/

Comment: What role/tasks does your user account have on that page?

Comment: Insights, Apps & Integration

Comment: Does anything change, when you use the option to let the app access all your current & future pages, in the login dialog?

Comment: Quickly checked it, but no nothing changes.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what is actually going on then. Not sure if this could somehow be related to which app _type_ you chose when you created it (but seeing how you are able to _grant_ the permissions, that might not be it either, I think with the wrong app type you should not even be able to ask for them in the first place(?).)

Comment: The app type I chose was/is "Business" because the graph API was explicitly named within it.

Comment: I had this problem and ended up having to uninstall my app and reinstall it. You'll find that on the dropdown where you select User or Page tokens. Also, just FYI, Facebook quietly deactivated a lot of deprecated APi calls in mid-Sept. One of these is Events. That one no longer works. I made a different way to get events using the Page feed instead.

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for the comment. I tried that but the error still persists. I think that somehow something is wrong with my account. :-/ It is quite odd that after selecting "page-access token" it automatically switches back to "user token"